# What do 48 and 87 values refer to when converting hexadecimal to decimal number in C?

Tags: c, numbers, hex, decimal, radix

I am trying to understand the process of converting a hexadecimal number to its decimal equivalent, in particular when converting each hexadecimal digit to its decimal value.

Say when the digit `i` of hexVal equals any characters ranging from '0' to '9', its decVal equals the hexVal subtracted by 48 and then timed by the digitBase:

```
if ((hexVal[i] >= '0') && (hexVal[i] <= '9')) {
    decVal += (hexVal[i] - 48) * digitBase;
    ...
}
```

I understand that 48 is ASCII value of '0'. 
What I am in doubt with is where the values 55 and 87 come from when digit `i` of hexVal equals the ranges 'A' to 'F' and 'a' to 'f':

```
else if ((hexVal[i] >= 'A') && (hexVal[i] <= 'F')) {
    hexToDec += (hexVal[i] - 55) * digitBase;
    ...
}
```

and

```
else if ((hexVal[i] >= 'a') && (hexVal[i] <= 'f')) {
    hexToDec += (hexVal[i] - 87) * digitBase;
    ...
}
```

The code blocks above are extracted from the following function which works well to convert hexadecimal numbers to their equivalent decimals.

```
int conv_hex_to_dec(char hexVal[]) {

    int hexToDec = 0;
    int len = strlen(hexVal);
    int digitBase = 1; 

    // Extract hex characters as digits from last character
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if ((hexVal[i] >= '0') && (hexVal[i] <= '9')) {
            hexToDec += (hexVal[i] - 48) * digitBase;
            digitBase = digitBase * 16;
        }

        else if ((hexVal[i] >= 'A') && (hexVal[i] <= 'F')) {
            hexToDec += (hexVal[i] - 55) * digitBase; 
            digitBase = digitBase * 16;
        }
        else if ((hexVal[i] >= 'a') && (hexVal[i] <= 'f')) {
            hexToDec += (hexVal[i] - 87) * digitBase; 
            digitBase = digitBase * 16;
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid hex val");
        }
    }

    return hexToDec;
}
```

Any explanation will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ And this would be why we shouldn't use the magic number 48 but instead type `'0'`.

Comment: That's string in hex representation conversion to int. Subtracting the ascii value to obtain the actual decimal value of a character. i.e. 9 is the ascii value of `'9' - '0'`

Comment: "following function which works well to convert hexadecimal numbers to their equivalent decimals" ---> only up to `INT_MAX`.  Beyond that, code is UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

48 is the ASCII code for '0'; the ASCII codes for 'A' and 'a' are  65 (55 = 65-10) and 97 (87 = 97 - 10) respectively.

Answer (score 2):

This is a prime example of why "magic numbers" in code are bad.

This code makes the assumption that the character encoding is ASCII.  The relevant numbers are:

- 48: the ASCII code for `'0'`
- 65: the ASCII code for `'A'`
- 97: the ASCII code for `'a'`

So in this line of code:

```
decVal += (hexVal[i] - 48) * digitBase;
```

It is subtracting the ASCII code of `hexVal[i]` from the ASCII code for `'0'`.  This converts a character in the range `'0'` to `'9'` to a value in the range 0 to 9.

Similarly, this:

```
hexToDec += (hexVal[i] - 55) * digitBase;
```

Subtracting the ASCII code of `hexVal[i]` from the ASCII code of `'A'` and adds 10, This converts a character in the range `'A'` to `'F'` to a value in the range 10 to 15.  Similarly, the check with 87, this converts a character in the range `'a'` to `'f'` to a value in the range 10 to 15.

A better way to write this would be:

```
    if ((hexVal[i] >= '0') && (hexVal[i] <= '9')) {
        hexToDec += (hexVal[i] - '0') * digitBase;
        digitBase = digitBase * 16;
    }

    else if ((hexVal[i] >= 'A') && (hexVal[i] <= 'F')) {
        hexToDec += (hexVal[i] - 'A' + 10) * digitBase; 
        digitBase = digitBase * 16;
    }
    else if ((hexVal[i] >= 'a') && (hexVal[i] <= 'f')) {
        hexToDec += (hexVal[i] - 'a' + 10) * digitBase; 
        digitBase = digitBase * 16;
    }
```

As it is more clear to the reader what the intention is.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and for pointing to good coding practice.

Comment: *This* assumes that the character codes for 0-9 & a-f are each in sequence, which is probably true, but may not be (consider EBCDIC, which has a break in the codes for letters, although not in a-f).